# XamlParseException when custom control sets its DefaultStyleKey

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I'm working on a custom WPF control that derives directly from `Control`.  In my control's constructor, I set the `DefaultStyleKey` like so:

```
public MyControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
}
```

I define the style for the control in a `ResourceDictionary` named `MyControl.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          ...
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I link to this `ResourceDictionary` from my main `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <!-- set some application-wide styles for various controls -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBox.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ProgressBar.xaml"/>
      ...
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyControl.xaml"/>

  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I run the application, I get a `XamlParseException` with the message "**Initialization of 'MyControl' threw an exception.**"  The inner-most exception reads "**Cannot location resource 'button.xaml'**".  If I remove the `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl)` line from the constructor of `MyControl`, I have no problems running the application (although the control isn't visible, since it has no template set).

Am I specifying my control's default style incorrectly?  Why does the exception seem to be thrown from an unrelated part of the main `ResourceDictionary` (the import of `Button.xaml`)?

Answer (score 0):

using WPF you use the following ctor

```
static MyControl()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
}
```

If this is in an class library, you need to define a "Generic.xaml" file within a "Themes" folder in the project. Otherwise the theme style (MyControl style) can be defined in the App.xaml

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to have the same result as the setting the `DefaultStyleKey` in the non-static constructor.